# It's possible delete post that created from facebook site with facebook sdk?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

i want ask qustion about facebook sdk for c#.
it's possible delete post that created from facebook site with facebook sdk?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: sorry , i want make sure the answer. i already seek in google and i found answer that said no..

Answer (score 0):

Even though this may not be one of the most well written questions, and the answer to it could probably be found in a matter of seconds on Google, I'll try to answer it.

You can delete a post on a page by instantiating a `FacebookClient` with that page's access token and then passing the post id to the `Delete` method.

```
var pageAccessToken = GetPageAccessToken(pageId, accessToken);
var fb = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
fb.Delete(postId);
```

Comment: That only for page, how about update status? how i delete that with sdk?